# Php Include problems

Tags: php, include

I have problem with php inclusion, if I include file, I see error `Object not found`. I don't know what to do.. I tried to change paths to file but it didn't help. I see only error...
Html

```
<div id="search" class="fleft">
        <form action="lib/search.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="searchText" placeholder="Search tweet!">
            <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search"/>
        </form>
    </div>


<ul id="tweetDisplay">

            <p>Tweets: </p>
            <?php
include 'lib\search.php';
            $searchQuery = $_SESSION['searchQuery'];
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($searchQuery)){
            echo "----------------------------------------------";
            echo "<li>Nickname: ".$row['nickname']."</li><li>".$row['text']."</li><li class='date'>".$row['pubdate']."</li>";
            }
            ?>
        </ul>
```

PhP script

```
<?php
include "connect.php";
session_start();
if ($_POST['searchText']){

    $searchQuery = mysql_query("SELECT u.nickname, t.text, t.pubdate FROM 111212_tweets t INNER JOIN 111212_users AS u ON t.user_id = u.id WHERE t.text LIKE '%" . $_POST['searchText'] . "%' ORDER BY t.pubdate DESC");
        $_SESSION['searchQuery'] = $searchQuery;
         header('Location: ../main.php');

    }else {
        $searchQuery = mysql_query("SELECT u.nickname, t.text, t.pubdate FROM 111212_tweets t INNER JOIN 111212_users AS u ON t.user_id = u.id ORDER BY t.pubdate DESC");
      $_SESSION['searchQuery'] = $searchQuery;
            header('Location: ../main.php');
}


?>
```

Comment: How do these two files fit together?

Comment: I include php script to html using `include 'lib\search.php';` search.php is a script file name. I found that i wrote `'lib\search.php'` with mistake I wrote wrong slash, but when I edited it, nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Windows? If yes, you need double slash in your paths: `include 'lib\\search.php';`

UPDATE: You need insert `<?php session_start(); ?>` or include your file at the top of your first file.

You have an error because you're calling `session_start();` in second file, after your php output data, and you need call `session_start();` before any output was sent to browser.

**UPDATE**: Change `header('Location: ../main.php');` for `header('Location: main.php');`

You need delete your second redirect (header location):

```
<?php
include "connect.php";
session_start();
if ($_POST['searchText']){
    $searchQuery = mysql_query("SELECT u.nickname, t.text, t.pubdate FROM 111212_tweets t INNER JOIN 111212_users AS u ON t.user_id = u.id WHERE t.text LIKE '%" . $_POST['searchText'] . "%' ORDER BY t.pubdate DESC");
    $_SESSION['searchQuery'] = $searchQuery;
    header('Location: ../main.php');
}else {
    $searchQuery = mysql_query("SELECT u.nickname, t.text, t.pubdate FROM 111212_tweets t INNER JOIN 111212_users AS u ON t.user_id = u.id ORDER BY t.pubdate DESC");
    $_SESSION['searchQuery'] = $searchQuery;
}
?>
```

Comment: Didn't work. When I include my script i see an error, but I have a redirect back to page, maybe problems somewhere in redirect?? But it will be strange because i used same path in another scripts and it worked

Comment: it's better to use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR instead of '\\'

Comment: I'm using `"lib/search.php"` right now, but i have the same result

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to say, that i inserted `session_start(); ` at the astart of my 1st file. now I included my file near session start, but it still shows me an error

Comment: `Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404`

Comment: Loading.... loading.. then i got an error where i read something like this `cycle redirect detected`

Comment: Ok! I updated, you need delete your second redirect, because you are in main.php

Comment: oh, Thank you. You helped me some much. If you have more time , please help me  change sql query, how i see it doesen't work correctly, I'm talking about first query in PhP file

Comment: It's because you are storing mysql_query result in $_SESSION var, you should store only plain SQL and take this in your first file and do mysql_query; it's because I don't know what are doing php to store your mysql result.

Comment: em, didn't give any effect. I have a suspicion that I don't get `$_POST['searchText']` , how can I check it?

Comment: To debug, add `echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); echo '</pre>';`

Comment: Thank you. I was right, searchText undifined... Do you know how to fix it? I'm trying to get this value using from at the beggining of this topic